# Spring 3 Web MVC error - requested URL /app-context/page-name was not found on this server

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, url, tomcat

I am new to Spring and I developed my first spring mvc web app using sts/eclipse.

I need your help on this error that surfaced after deployment to my webhost.

Please note that this small app works fine within eclipse’s tomcat server.

The spring app’s context path ( application context)  is ‘*realtyguide*’.

Webhost server is  a private Tomcat 5.5.  The app was packaged as a maven war package.  I deployed the war file (unzipped it) on my webhost as a virtual host (with Context path = "/realtyguide" in server.xml) .

The index of the website is accessed thru http://mysite.com/realtyguide/

The index page comes up fine but when accessing  the other web pages referenced from the index page the browser returns the errorr:

*“The requested URL  /realtyguide/page-name  was not found on this server."*

I verified that the index page detected my application context because I used c:url and spring:url for my links and the page source of the index page show the context path in my links, such as `href="/realtyguide/resources/styles/standard.css”`  and

```
<a href="/realtyguide/testpage" >Test - next page</a>
```

It seems like the controller is not detecting the mapped URLs . Could this be the cause of this error?

Here is the web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

  <display-name>Realty Guide</display-name>

      <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

      <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the root-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    </beans>
```

Here is the Spring application servlet configuration (servlet-context.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springproject.realtyguide" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->    
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>   

    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>      


    <!-- Bean to provide Internationalization  -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:META-INF/spring/database.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- __________ BEAN ENTRIES FOR TILES 2 -->

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
        <property name="order" value="0"/> 
        <property name="viewClass"> 
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView </value>
        </property>
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.tiledef"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jstlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="order" value="1"/> 
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
    </bean> 

    <!-- __________ END OF BEAN ENTRIES FOR TILES 2 -->

    <!-- Resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to allow for theme support -->
    <bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
        <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">  
        <property name="defaultThemeName" value="standard" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here are some controler handler methods

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(@ModelAttribute("searchFormBean") SearchFormBean searchFormBean, Model model) {


    model.addAttribute("searchFormBean", searchFormBean);       

    return "index.tiledef";     // 'index' is a Tile definition in tiles.xml,

      }


      @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("searchFormBean") SearchFormBean searchFormBean, 
                            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, Model model) {

    searchFormValidator.validate(searchFormBean, result);           
    if (result.hasErrors()) {                                       
        model.addAttribute("searchFormBean", searchFormBean);       
        return "index.tiledef";                                     
    } else {
        String searchTerm = searchFormBean.getSearchTerm(); 
        searchTerm = searchTerm.replaceAll(" ","_");                
        return "redirect:/propertylistings/" + searchTerm + "/1";   // If no errors - display the listings page
    }
 }


@RequestMapping("/testpage")
public String gotoNextPage() {
    return "nextpage.tiledef";
}
```

This is the webhosts tomcat/conf/**server.xml**

I deleted most of the 'commented out' stuff to make it shorter.

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                <Server port="9200" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

                  <!-- Comment these entries out to disable JMX MBeans support used for the 
                       administration web application -->
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>

                  <!-- Global JNDI resources -->
                  <GlobalNamingResources>

                    <!-- Test entry for demonstration purposes -->
                    <Environment name="simpleValue" type="java.lang.Integer" value="30"/>

                    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
                         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users -->
                    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                       description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                           factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" readonly="true" />

                  </GlobalNamingResources>


                  <!-- Define the Tomcat Stand-Alone Service -->
                  <Service name="Catalina">


                    <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
                    <Connector port="9201" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                               maxThreads="10" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
                               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
                               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />

                    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
                    <Connector port="9203" 
                               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />


                    <!-- Define the top level container in our container hierarchy -->
                    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">


                      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
                           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
                           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
                           available for use by the Realm.  -->
                      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>


                      <!-- Define the default virtual host
                           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
                       -->
                      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
                       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

                       </Host>

                       <Host name="mysite.com" appBase="/home/tsoriano/public_html">
                          <Alias>www.mysite.com</Alias> 
                          <Alias>mysite.com</Alias> 
                          <Context path="/realtyguide" reloadable="true" docBase="realtyguide" debug="0"/>
                          <Context path="/manager" debug="0" privileged="true"
                              docBase="/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/server/webapps/manager">
                          </Context>
                       </Host>  

                    </Engine>

                  </Service>

                </Server>
```

This small app works fine in eclipse/springsource tool suite.

What is the solution to this URL not found error? Please help me.

**Problem solved**

I suspected that my webhost's server may be misconfigured but I have no way to check because I have a shared hosting plan. To verify that the problem is not with my app, I deployed the app in a local Tomcat outside of eclipse in my laptop. It runs perfect.

So I reported again to tech support that "*Tomcat servlet is not loading*". I insisted to tech support that the problem is on their end. That there might be something wrong with their apache configuration. Apache is not talking correctly to Tomcat.

They finally did fix it and this is the confirmation I received from them - "We have changed some settings in the server configuration file so that all the requests to your domain will be handled by tomcat instead of Apache."

I hope this helps someone who is in a shared hosting plan and encounters the same error. If you feel that your Tomcat server is properly set but still keep getting URL not found errors, insist on your tech support to look at their server configuration. Or get a dedicated server if you can afford it so you have total control on your apache server and tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the lines in your .xml

```
<!-- Enables annotated methods on POJO @Controllers  -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<!-- Enables plain Controllers (e.g. FlowController) -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem still persist. I deployed this to my local macine's tomcat and the app worked perfect. I don't understand why it has this errors in the webhost. I checked the catalina.out file and it does show mapping to my controllers. Here's a snippet: 'INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Root mapping to handler 'homeController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/testpage] onto handler 'homeController''